# BigQuery partitioned tables join on _PARTITIONTIME

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Having two partitioned tables (both with pseudo-column _PARTITIONTIME) I want to join them on _PARTITIONTIME. Then I want to query resulting table with _PARTITIONTIME filter, but what I noticed is that this filter is propagated only to the first table of the JOIN statement. Below is an example.

```
WITH tab1 AS (
  SELECT
    _PARTITIONTIME AS pt,
    country
  FROM
    `some_partitioned_table1`
    ),
tab2 AS (
  SELECT
    _PARTITIONTIME AS pt,
    country
  FROM
    `some_partitioned_table2`
    ),
merged_tab AS (
  SELECT pt, country
  FROM tab1 JOIN tab2
  USING (pt, country) )

SELECT *
FROM merged_tab
WHERE pt = "2018-08-12"
```

In my case this query processes ~26 GB.
Flipping JOIN order to

```
FROM tab2 JOIN tab1
```

results in processing ~60 GB. Obviously **pt** filter is propagated to the first table in JOIN.
What I really want to achieve is following:

```
WITH tab1 AS (
  SELECT
    _PARTITIONTIME AS pt,
    country
  FROM
    `some_partitioned_table1`
    ),
tab2 AS (
  SELECT
    _PARTITIONTIME AS pt,
    country
  FROM
    `some_partitioned_table2`
    ),
merged_tab AS (
  SELECT t1.pt as pt1, t2.pt as pt2, t1.country
  FROM tab1 t1 JOIN tab2 t2
  ON t1.pt = t2.pt AND t1.country = t2.country
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  merged_tab
WHERE
  pt1 = "2018-08-12" AND pt2 = "2018-08-12"
```

This processes ~100MB.
Is this behaviour (propagating **pt** filter to only first table) by any means desired or expected? Maybe are there some tricks to achieve this with only one **pt** filter? Or maybe I'm missing something?
Mentioned query was intended to create view which would be queried with pt filter.
Note I'm using standard SQL.

Comment: This looks like a case that is not supported for partition pruning yet. Please file a feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0 if you'd like it to be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such optimization has been implemented and it's supported now.

Comment: Can you expand your answer and make it more useful? Perhaps mention the version number where this support was first added? Maybe a link to the issue tracker or blog post announcing its deployment? Use the [edit] link.

Comment: We gradually rolled out this feature. From yesterday, it's rolled out to all users.

Comment: I'm currently writing a query like this, and the propagation is not working. The query uses 5 views of tables that are partitioned.

Comment: This answer seems to contradict the documentation: ["To limit the partitions that are scanned in a query, use a constant expression in your filter. If you use dynamic expressions in your query filter, BigQuery must scan all of the partitions."](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pruning_limiting_partitions). It would be appreciated if you can elaborate in which cases partition elimination would be done as you say.