# BigQuery joining time-unit column-partitioned tables

Tags: google-bigquery

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149176/bigquery-partitioned-tables-join-on-partitiontime), however concerning time-unit column-partitioned tables instead of ingestion-time partitioned tables (hence there is no `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo-column).

Consider two tables A and B, each with a `date` column used for daily partitioning.

These tables are joined using a full outer join, as follows:

```
SELECT
    date,
    A.date AS A_date,
    B.date AS B_date,
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B USING(date)
```

Filtering this table using `WHERE A_date = '2021-01-01'` will process 20.6MB

Filtering this table using `WHERE B_date = '2021-01-01'` will process 10.9MB

Filtering this table using `WHERE date = '2021-01-01'` will process 31.5MB

Filtering this table using `WHERE A_date = '2021-01-01' AND B_date = '2021-01-01'` will process **only 65.6KB**

I would expect that using `date` would also process only 65.6KB, however it seems like the time-partitioning is simply ignored. Is this intentional behavior, or is there any way to remedy this?

Comment: It seems like Problem cloud be because of Time Partition, you can try changing table to Date Partition. So it will start scanning data for whole day and it will give you a better understanding how it works. Ideally Time partition takes '00:00:00' and it will process data for a particular timestamp ''

Comment: Both tables are partitioned with daily granularity, and the result is the same whether the partitioned columns are of type DATE or TIMESTAMP.

Comment: True, but if Partition type is either date or Hourly then result data will not be same. Can you check on that front.

Comment: In that case it would not be the same, but in my case both tables are partitioned by "Day".